# Yii2 - how to pass parameters in event

Tags: yii, yii2

I need to pass additional parameters when the event is fired. How can I do this.

```
const EVENT_NEW_PORTAL = 'new-portal';

public function init(){

      $this->on(self::EVENT_NEW_PORTAL, [$this, $userID, 'defaultJournal']);
      $this->on(self::EVENT_NEW_PORTAL, [$this->idportal, $userID, 'defaultCategory']);

    }

    public function defaultJournal($portal, $userID)
    {
        CsJournal::insertDefaultJournal($portal, $userID);
    }

    public function defaultBoardCagetory($portalID, $userID)
    {
        BoardCategories::createDefaultCategory($portal, $userID);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this : [Attaching Event Handlers](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#attaching-event-handlers).

> When attaching an event handler, you may provide additional data as the third parameter to `yii\base\Component::on()`. The data will be made available to the handler when the event is triggered and the handler is called.

e.g. :

```
public function defaultJournal($event)
{
    CsJournal::insertDefaultJournal($this, $event->data);
}
```

And then :

```
$this->on(self::EVENT_NEW_PORTAL, [$this, 'defaultJournal'], $userID);
```